# Java syntax issues

Tags: java, compilation, josephus

I'm trying to do a Josephus problem, but I'm not allowed to use code snippets from other people. With this in mind, I have 27 errors in my code, but can't figure out how to fix it. Would you wonderful people explain to me why it won't compile. I want to see if my logic is flawed, but I can't test it because it won't compile. Any other tips are more than welcome! Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Josephus
{
    public class Link
    {
        public int num;
        public Link next;

        public Link (int d)
        {
            num = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    public class Main
    {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many players");

        int numPlayers = in.nextInt();
        Link first, last;
        first = last = new Link (1);

        for(int k=2; k<=numPlayers; k++)
        {
            last.next = new Link(k);
            last = last.next;
        }
        last.next = first;

        System.out.println("How many skips");
        int m = in.nextInt();

        for (int g=0; g<numPlayers; g++)
        {
            for (int k=0; k<=m; k++);
            {
                last = last.next;
            }
            last.next;
            last = last.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using an IDE with syntax highlight..

Comment: What IDE are you using?  Eclipse?

Comment: -1 for not quoting at least the first 2-3 errors.

Comment: Aside from the obvious syntax errors, watch out for this: `first = last = new Link (1);`. It's dangerous. Objects are not like primitives. The 2 variable will reference THE SAME object. You probably want 2 different objects there...

Comment: Ok my instructor is requiring us to use Jgrasp. The errors are "identifier expected" and points at parenthesis, but now there are only 4 errors after using the " public static void Main (String[] args) " solution  first is the same error pointing to the space between class and void in public static void Main (String[] args). The next error is  invalid method declaration; return type required
public class void Main (String [] args). This error points at the capital M. Next error is error: not a statement
last.next; this points to the period in between last and next. The last one I can fix.

Comment: Radu, that was what I was intending since they both reference the first item in a linked list. Is there a possible issue with this that I don't know about?

Comment: Zavior, what IDE would you suggest? I'm willing to learn a new IDE if it helps me better than Jgrasp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up a bit your code so it compiles, you might be better off with two classes

Josephus.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Josephus {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many players");

    int numPlayers = in.nextInt();
    Link first = new Link(1);
    Link last = new Link(1);

    for (int k = 2; k <= numPlayers; k++) {
        last.next = new Link(k);
        last = last.next;
    }
    last.next = first;
    first.next = last;

    System.out.println("How many skips");
    int m = in.nextInt();

    for (int g = 0; g < numPlayers; g++) {
        for (int k = 0; k <= m; k++)
        {
            last = last.next;
        }
        // last.next;
        last = last.next;
    }

    in.close();
}
}
```

and Link.java

```
public class Link {

    public int num;
    public Link next;

    public Link(int d) {
        num = d;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

This compiles and accepts input, then throws an error. I haven't fixed that since I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve.

**Changes:**

1. Changed `"class main"` to `public static void main(){...)` The Java runtime will look for this method when it's called.
2. Extracted class `Link` to it's own file other solutions are possible, like some other answers say, you could declare it as static or instantiate `Josephus` (and probably some other ways)
3. Commented out the line `last.next`, this doesn't actually solve any problem, it just eliminates the compilation error and allows you to compile, since I don't see what you're trying to do here I couldn't think of a better solution.
4. It's not necessary to compile but I added the line `in.close();` at the end of the main method to free allocated resources, without this line it'll throw a compile warning.
5. Added `first.next = last;` to avoid the null pointer exception that was happening.

All that you should need now is to implement the Josephus logic inside the nested loops and output your results (if desired) all of which should be quite language agnostic.

Comment: The purpose of the program is to use link lists to make a circular list and at specific intervals delete numbers until only one is left. Thank you for using my code, and I don't want to be a bother, but can you explain why those changes fixed things?

Comment: Like some other users suggested, the easiest thing for you to do might be to paste your code into an editor, I suggest Eclipse. The IDE will highlight the errors in your code and give you an explanation for most of them. Some things I'll add an edit explaining some of the modifications.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
public class Main
```

You want

```
public static void main(String [] args)
```

Comment: This is a good start. Without a clearer picture of the overall purpose of the program hard to make any other specific recommendations. Any assumptions or interpretations from analyzing the current implementation may lead to misinformation.

Comment: The purpose of the program is to use link lists to make a circular list and at specific intervals delete numbers until only one is left.

Answer (score 0):

One other problem of with your code is that you have an non static inner class `Link` and you try to instantiate it without an enclosing instance of the containing class `Josephus`.

So either make is static

```
public static class Link
```

or instantiate it using an instance of enclosing class

```
Josephus outer = new Josephus();
first = last = outer.new Link (1);
// ...
last.next = outer.new Link(k);
```

Better yet, move the class into a own compilation unit, i.e a file `Link.java` until you learn about [inner classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

And the line

```
last.next;
```

is not correct. What are you trying to do with `last.next`? You have to assign it to some other variable. I don't think you need it anyways, just remove it.

Comment: I'm trying to move the link from one item in the list to skip one and point to one after that so essentially it "deletes" an item from the linked list since no pointers point to that item anymore.

Comment: I don't understand the enclosing class thing at all. Would you be awesome enough to explain it to me??

Comment: @user2738094 When you declare a class `Foo` and  inside the declaration of that class, i.e. between the opening `{` and the closing `}`, you declare another class `Bar` then `Bar` is called an `inner class`, and as for everything which is inside, there must be something enclosing it, and this is the class `Foo`. So `Foo` is the outer class - also called a top.level class - which encloses the inner class `Bar`. In your case `Josephus` is an outer class enclosing the inner class `Link`. Please read the documentation in the link I pasted for inner classes, it is explained better there.